# Not Upgraded Assets Files

Tags: php, nginx, caching, opcache

I'm trying to update the CSS and JS file but I can not see this change on the site. Even,  when I go to the CSS file with the address bar. I see an old version of the file.

*I see the file updated when I access the file via FTP.*

**What have I done?**

Added version to files, for example:

```
https://example.com/style.css?v=2 => Didn't work
```

I restarted the services

```
[root@server ~]# systemctl restart nginx.service && systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

I deleted the [Opcache](http://php.net/manual/tr/book.opcache.php)'s cache

```
php-fpm-cli -r 'var_dump(opcache_get_status());' -connect /var/run/php-fpm.sock
```

With private windows of browser. **Didn't work.**

I accessed the file from a **different** computer. **Didn't work.**

and, finally I restarted the server: I'm still seeing not updated CSS and JS files!

What could be the problem?

> Server;
>
> PHP 7.1, Nginx & PHP-FPM

Comment: Either the location you check with FTP does not match the file accessed via URL (different directory, wrong server etc.) or there is a agressively-caching proxy server in between the server and your network. As per my experience, the first case is usually what happened.

Comment: There's only HAproxy. There is no cache server other than that @JiriHrazdil